# Mutating and Plotting in R

Tags: r, plot, dplyr

Q: An assistant is “on time” if he/she runs an errand and returns to the office either on time or earlier than expected, regardless of delays in their departure. For this exercise, create a new variable to classify if the assistant “on time” or “delayed”. For “on time” arrivals, plot the distribution of the departure delays. What percent of the assistants trips that had a delay in departure ended up being on time?

[image]
*departure time is in military time. If a number in a "delay" field is negative, that means the assistant left for the errand earlier than scheduled.

I have been able to come up with the following code but I am very stuck on how to proceed with this problem.

```
assistant_delays <- assistant_trip_data %>%
  mutate(arrival_type = ifelse(arrival_delay <= 0, "on time", "delayed"))
assistant_delays
```

Comment: With `ggplot2`, use `geom_histogram()` to create a histogram chart that shows the distribution of delays. To calculate the percentage, use `filter()` to only select cases whose departure delay is greater than 0, use `count()` to count the categories in `arrival_type` and then create a new variable that proportionalizes that by dividing n by the sum of n.

Comment: OK, I have tried this but am getting errors. I am very new to this and cannot figure out why I cannot use "count" here and get an error:

```{r}
depart_delays %>%
  group_by(arrival_type) %>%
  filter(arrival_type == "on time") %>%
  summarize(rate = count(arrival_type) / n())
depart_delays
```

Also, I am trying to use a scatter plot and this is what I have:
```{r}
ggplot(data = depart_delays, aes(x = arrival_type, y = departure_delay)) +
 geom_point()
```

Comment: Adding to what @Phil said, the distribution of delays is for "on time" arrivals, so use `filter()` to only select trips with "on time" arrivals before plotting.

Comment: @RyanWilliams, `count()` creates a two-column data frame with one column as the unique values in your provided vector (`arrival_type`) and the second column as the number of times each of those values appeared. You don't need to use `summarize()` on it. Consider how else you can use its information from `count()` to obtain your percentage.

Comment: Also notice that if you use `filter(arrival_type == "on time")` and then use `count(arrival_type)`, you will only get the count for "on time" arrivals. Sum of n would equal to the n of "on time" arrivals only (and the percentage of "on time" arrivals would be 100%). This isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: I see what youre saying! So I took out the arrival type "on time" filter and tried to use count. However, I dont think I am using the function properly. (Again, this is all new to me so I apologize for the terrible code):

```{r}
depart_delays %>%
  group_by(arr_type) %>%
  summarize(count(arr_type == "on time") / n())
depart_delays
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For “on time” arrivals, plot the distribution of the departure delays.

When I have to plot a distribution, one of the first visuals that cross my mind would be a histogram (a.k.a. a frequency distribution plot). Hence, you can use `geom_histogram()` from the `ggplot2` R package to plot the distribution of the departure delays for "on time" arrivals. It will plot the number of times each value in the vector (`departure_delay`) occurred (or bin them—group nearby ones into a bar—if the vector is continuous/numeric/integer).

```r
assistant_delays %>% 
    filter(arrival_type == "on time") %>% # for "on time" arrivals only
    ggplot(aes(x = departure_delay)) + geom_histogram()
```

> What percent of the assistants trips that had a delay in departure ended up being on time?

```r
delayed_trips <- assistant_delays %>% 
    filter(departure_delay > 0) %>% # subset to trips that had a departure delay
    count(arrival_type) %>% # shows how many arrived "on time" or "delayed"
    mutate(percentage = n/sum(n)*100) # percent of "on time" and "delayed" arrivals

delayed_trips # observe the table

delayed_trips$percentage[delayed_trips$arrival_type == "on time"] # answer
```

The percent of assistant trips that had a delay in departure and ended up being on time will be shown in `delayed_trips`.

I recommend running `?ggplot2::geom_histogram` and `?dplyr::count` to learn more about those functions.

Credit goes to [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221626/phil) for first describing this solution in the comments above.

Comment: You got it. Also, if you offer any tutoring in R for a fee please drop me your contact information. I would potentially be interested.